# Returning results that have a certain alphabet such as 'c' and cannot have the alphabet appear thereafter

Tags: postgresql

Good day all.

I have a problem that requires me to return a result with an alphabets as the third character but cannot appear again afterwards. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT product_name, model_year, list_price
FROM production.products
WHERE product_name like '__c%'
```

However this will return results with the alphabet 'c' as the third character and still 'c' appear in the product_name again.
Any comments will be great appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex like here:

```sql
SELECT product_name, model_year, list_price
FROM production.products
WHERE product_name ~* '^..c[^c]*$';
```

The regex pattern `^..c[^c]*$` will match any product name having `c` (or `C`) as the third character, provided that `c` does *not* appear later in the same name.

You *could* also do this using `LIKE` as follows:

```sql
SELECT product_name, model_year, list_price
FROM production.products
WHERE product_name LIKE '__c%' AND product_name NOT LIKE '__c%c%';
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for the comment, however as part of my assessment I am confine to using the function of LIKE to solve the problem. But still thank you for your help.

Comment: @archterr Check my updated answer for a version using `LIKE`.